# how can select a value from a dataframe column if another column of this dataframe equal to an other dataframe column value?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a df1 dataframe and df2 dataframe.now i want to select a value that if one value in df2 column1 equal to df1 column1 then select df2 column2 value.

Answer (score 0):

You need the merge df1 and df2 first to create df3 and then you can select from df3. Look at this  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html
This is how you merge 2 dfs

Comment: df1 and df2 are so big with different size.is there any way easier with functions?

Comment: Diffrent sizes is not a problem at all when you merge, its very common. If iT has too many columns, you can select the columns you want before merging.